# Changing Mule Flow Threading Profile at runtime

Tags: mule

I have a requirement in hand where I need to change the Mule Flow Threading Behavior at runtime without the need of bouncing the whole Mule Container. I figured out few different ways to achieve this, but none of them are working.

1. I tried accessing the Mule Context Registry and from there I was trying to do a lookup of "FlowConstructLifecycleManager" Object so that I can tap in there and access the threading profile of the object and reset those values, then stop and start the flow programmatically in order to get the change applied in the flow. I am stuck in this approach as I was unable to get hold of the FlowConstructLifecycleManager Object neither from the Mule Spring Registry nor from the Transient Registry. I was able to get hold of the Flow object though which has a direct reference to that FlowConstructLifecycleManager Object. But, unfortunately, they made this object as protected and didn't expose any method for us to access this object.
2. Since I was unable to access this FlowConstructLifecycleManager directly from Mule implemented Flow class, I decided to extend this Flow class and just add another public method to it so that I can access FlowConstructLifecycleManager object from Flow object programmatically. But, I am stuck in this approach as well as even if I am putting my version of the same Flow class packaged and dropped in lib/user folder of the container, it is still not picking up my version of the class, and loading the original version instead.

It would be of great help if I can get any pointer on the approach of solving either my first or second problem.

Thanks in advance,
Ananya

Comment: Can you let me know why would you want such a requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

In our company, we are building a dashboard from where we should be able to start/stop any flow or change the processing power of any flow by increasing/ decreasing the active threads for a flow or changing the pollen polling frequency. All of these should be done at runtime without any server downtime.

Anyway, I made it working finally. I had to patch up the mule-core jar and expose few objects so that I can get to the thread profile object and tweak the values at runtime and stop/ start the flow to reflect the changes to take effect. I know this is little bit messy and but it works.

Thanks,
Ananya